# Mismatched tag, expected meta

Tags: html, meta

I have the following HTML that is generating a mismatched tag error in Firefox:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252;">
        <title>XYZ</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    hello
    </body>
</html>
```

Since the [meta tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_meta.asp) takes no closing tag, I do not understand why I am getting this error.

[image]

Comment: Do you have a doctype defined?

Comment: @Soviut what is a doctype? I have pasted the complete HTML page that is being loaded and generating the error.

Comment: Remove the `;` in `charset=windows-1252;`

Comment: @j08691 That does not eliminate the error

Comment: Which is why I posted it as a comment and not an answer. Just making a note of it for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a doctype otherwise some browsers will automatically assume certain doc modes. Certain modes like XHTML require you close all tags.

The way you'd close tags in these stricter modes is by adding a `/` to the end of the tag.

```
<meta ... />
```

Instead, you should always define a doctype. Add the following to the top of your HTML to put it into HTML5 mode.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

This will accept tags like `<meta>`, `<hr>` and `<br>` that don't have closing tags.

**NOTE:** This might be a long standing bug in Firefox. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=501838

Comment: Adding doctype to the page does not change anything, the same error is generated. My meta tag is right out of  w3schools.com and the same kind of meta tag with no closing slash can be found in millions of web pages.

Comment: It might be a firefox bug, I've updated the answer. Either way, you should have `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the top of your document.

Comment: Had this error. The solution as indicated above is to close the meta with the final "/".

Comment: According to w3schools.com, meta should be like `<meta ... >`. However, I use QDomElement also prompt the mismatch tag error.